# JWT Exp 24hrs Meaning?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am a little confused about what exactly it means to have a JWT expiration time of 24 hrs. What does this mean in terms of being automatically logged out (every 24hrs?)? What would happen if someone keeps using the system for more than 24 hrs? What would happen if the system is inactive for more than 24 hrs?

Answer (score 0):

The expiration time of a JWT is merely a [claim](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html#rfc.section.4.1.4); in other words, the server can choose (this being the operative word) not to process the token when a certain timestamp has passed.

It completely depends on the JWT implementation in use if it will enforce the expiration, or if the developer has to do that manually.

For instance, the [`jsonwebtoken`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) package's default setting is to fail verification for JWT's if they have expired. However, you can [tell it to ignore the expiration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwt-verify-token-secretorpublickey-options-callback).

This also means that the developer has to choose when to update the expiration time of a token (a fixed amount of time after logging in, or after last interacting with the server, or something else entirely).

Comment: I guess my question really comes down to this. Does a user have to log in at least once every 24 hrs if a token exp is set to 24 hrs?

Comment: @axc the expiration date in a token is _merely_ a piece of information (whereas with cookies, the browser enforces the expirate date by deleting cookies that have expired). How your application is going to interpret that information is entirely up to you.

Comment: [RFC 7519](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.4) states that `The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.`  (Implementers MAY tolerate a small skew).  It is not "up to the JWT implementation" - if an implementation accepts an expired token, it is not an implementation of JWT :)

Comment: @frasertweedale fair enough, but from a server standpoint, it's still up to the developer to (not) handle expired tokens (unlike cookies, which don't get sent to the server after expiration)